# Estatus: 401 Unauthorized - Error desplegando artefacto jar en Gitlab Artifactory

Tags: java, maven, deployment, gitlab, jar

He estado teniendo este error al intentar desplegar artefactos jar en Gitlab Artifactory, les comparto los pasos que realicé siguiendo la documentación de gitlab :

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/

1. Primero modifiqué mi settings.xml, añadiendo mi token de acceso personal así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. He creado un grupo y un repositorio dentro para el artefacto como se ve a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. He especificado en el pom.xml de mi proyecto que genera el artefacto jar, la dirección con el ID del grupo y el repositorio, de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y además tengo las siguientes configuraciones de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Puedo generar el jar del proyecto sin ningún problema, pero cuando escribo mvn deploy para desplegar mi proyecto en el repositorio de artefactos de gitlab, obtengo el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola BRUNO, estás en SOes, el idioma del sitio es el español, podrías editar tu pregunta, traducirla, quitar la imágenes que contienen texto y agregar tu código y los mensajes de error como texto?, muchas gracias!!.

Comment: para maven central normalmente pones tus credenciales en el archivo `settings.xml` de casualidad revisaste el contenido de dicho archivo antes de intentad desplegar?

Comment: He modifico mi archivo settings.xml como lo muestro en el punto 1, te refieres a eso? O se debe modificar en otro lado